# Error at calling a stored procedure mysql SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, mysql-error-1292

I had a stored procedure in MySQL by someone other as definer which was working fine till yesterday. The user (definer of the stored procedure) got deleted on Google cloud Platform.

I copied and created the stored procedure by my own user which is successfully created.
At the time of calling the procedure I get an error

```
SQL Error [1292] [22001]: Data truncation: Truncated incorrect date value: '2015-03-20 04:56:00.000000'
```

I am wondering why it was working fine until yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

There can be the following reasons:

1. Because you're using your own User-ID, you need to have access to the database and tables which were created by your definer.
2. [`SQL error 1292`](https://bobcares.com/blog/mysql-error-1292/#:%7E:text=Why%20does%20MySQL%20Error%201292%20occur&text=This%20error%20normally%20occurs%20when,a%20WHERE%20or%20ON%20clause.) occurs when your date format is incorrect.
   Insert date in the following format `yyyy-MM-dd`
3. Because your files might have been stored in back-up or cache, you're getting that "Data Truncation Error".